# android-async-http always onFailure (status code = 0), but DefaultHttpClient is all right

Tags: android, asynchronous, httprequest, androidhttpclient

I am try to use [android-async-http](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http), but always onFailure, and from the log I can see the status code = 0.  However, when I use the traditional way (org.apache.http.client.HttpClient), the status code = 200;

the code:

public class HttpTestActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_http_test);

    testHttp();
    testHttp2();
}

public void testHttp2() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.baidu.com");
            try {
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                Log.i("ws", "---->>22: status code: " + statusCode);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public void testHttp() {
    Log.i("ws", "---->>testHttp");
    VStarRestClient.get("http://www.baidu.com", null, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            Log.i("ws", "---->>onSuccess :" + statusCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            Log.i("ws", "---->>onFailure : " + statusCode);
        }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
        Log.i("ws", "---->>onFailure : " + error);
    }
    });
```

if you got the error as 0 means ,Check the error - field,
It displays the exact problem ,Like java.net.SocketTimeoutException , etc